# Is this a valid example of Class invariances using php 7 asserts?

Tags: php, class, liskov-substitution-principle, invariance

I am trying to understanding a little best the Class Invariances used by Liskov Principle.

I know that some languages [like D have native support to invariant](https://dlang.org/spec/contracts.html), but, using asserts in PHP I've tried combining magic methods and assert:

```
<?php

class Person {
    protected string $name;
    protected string $nickName;
    protected function testContract(){
        assert(($this->name != $this->nickName));
    }
    public function __construct(string $name, string $nickName){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->nickName = $nickName;
    }
    public function __set($name, $value){
        $this->testContract();
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
    public function __get($name){
        $this->testContract();
        return $this->$name;
    }
}

class GoodPerson extends Person {
    public function getFullName(){
        return $this->name." ".$this->nickName. "!!!";
    }
}

class BadPerson extends Person {
    protected function testContract(){
        assert(($this->name != ""));
    }
}

$gp = new GoodPerson("João", "Joãozinho");
echo $gp->nickName;
echo $gp->getFullName();
$bp = new BadPerson("João", "João");
echo $bp->nickName;
```

- Can I use assert to create a Contract?
- Is BadPerson a valid example to Liskov's Class Invariance violation on inheritance ?
- Is GoodPerson a valid example to Liskov's Classe Invariance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can I use assert to create a Contract?**

No

From [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php#refsect2-function.assert-unknown-descriptioo)

- Assertions should be used as a debugging feature only
- Assertions should not be used for normal runtime operations like input parameter checks

**Is BadPerson a valid example to Liskov's Class Invariance violation on inheritance?**

Yes

> Preconditions cannot be strengthened in a subtype.

But your code doesn't make any sense

First your `testContract` method will only be invoked if you try to set or get a dynamic property and it will check for the parameters you passed through the `constructor`

```
public function __set($name, $value){
    $this->testContract();
    $this->$name = $value;
}
```

Here you basically test the constructor parameters but in the magic method (`__set`)

So in order to make that check works you need to invoke the `__set` like this

```
$gp = new BadPerson("João", "Joãozinho");
$gp->name = ''; // This line here invokes __set magic method
```

So what you really need to do is get rid of `testContract` and put the check inside the base class constructor. Why? because your properties are `protected` so the only opportunity that clients have for setting them is through the constructor

```
public function __construct(string $name, string $nickName){
    if ($name != "" && $name != $nickName)
        throw new Exception('Name must not be empty and must not equal Nickname');

    $this->name = $name;
    $this->nickName = $nickName;
}
```

**Is GoodPerson a valid example to Liskov's Classe Invariance?**

Yes

Comment: Can I emulate invariant() from D on PHP?

Comment: @celsowm [This](https://github.com/php-deal/framework) may help. It's a Design by Contract framework for PHP.